# Cannot read property 'sourceAccount' of undefined - exception while binding select

Tags: angular

I am getting this error:

```
NewTransactionComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceAccount' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (NewTransactionComponent.html:4)
```

when I try to bind the select in my html. Basically, there will be two selects in same page filled with same data (accounts). I want to pass to service which account was chosen for each select but I am getting the error above.

new-transaction.component.html

```
<div>
  <div>
  <label>Source Account</label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="transaction.sourceAccount.id">
      <option *ngFor="let a of accounts" [value]="a.id" >{{a.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Source Account</label>
  <select  [(ngModel)]="transaction.targetAccount.id" >
      <option *ngFor="let a of accounts" [value]="a.id">{{a.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="transaction.amount">
</div>
<div>
    <button (click)="addTransaction()">Add</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

new-transaction.component.ts

```
export class NewTransactionComponent implements OnInit {

  accounts: Account[];
  transaction: Transaction;
  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private transactionService: TransactionService) { }

  addTransaction(): void {

    //this.transaction.amount= *** here I want fill the variable transaction so I can post it to rest service
    this.transactionService.addTransaction(this.transaction);

  }
```

...

My models:

transaction.ts

```
import { Account } from "./account";

export class Transaction {
    idtransaction: number;
    amount: number;
    sourceAccount: Account;
    targetAccount: Account;

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
      Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

account.ts

```
import { User } from "./user";

export class Account {
    id: number;
    name: string = '';
    user: User[] = [];

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
      Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

**** edited

```
export class NewTransactionComponent implements OnInit {

  accounts: Account[];
  transaction: Transaction = new Transaction;
  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private transactionService: TransactionService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.accountService
    .getAllAccounts()
    .subscribe(
      (accounts) => {
        this.accounts = accounts;
      }
    );
  }

  addTransaction(): void {
    this.transactionService.addTransaction(this.transaction);
    //this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least an empty Object of transaction before setting the `[(ngModel)]`. Otherwise transaction will be undefined.

Comment: you are right, I missed "... = new Transaction" but it is still not working. I am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Based on classes above, do you see anything wrong with <select  [(ngModel)]="transaction.targetAccount.id" > ?

Comment: again you need to set targetAccount as an empty object

Comment: please, can you make more clear? Isn't already done with transaction: Transaction = new Transaction; on top of my class ?

Comment: yeah ! inside transaction you have an object targetAccount which should be initailized as a empty object, otherwise you have targetAccount undefined. so you are getting the error id of undefined

Comment: after that transaction.targetAccount = new Account(); should work